# Generating a list of tuple in a specific order

Tags: python, list

So here is my problem. I have 2 frequencies, and I generate a list of tuple of frequencies nearby.

```
f1 = 20
f2 = 50
f = [(a, b) for a in range(f1-3, f1+4) for b in range(f2-3, f2+4)]
```

Output:

```
[(17, 47), (17, 48), (17, 49), (17, 50), (17, 51), (17, 52), (17, 53), (18, 47), (18, 48), (18, 49), (18, 50), (18, 51), (18, 52), (18, 53), (19, 47), (19, 48), (19, 49), (19, 50), (19, 51), (19, 52), (19, 53), (20, 47), (20, 48), (20, 49), (20, 50), (20, 51), (20, 52), (20, 53), (21, 47), (21, 48), (21, 49), (21, 50), (21, 51), (21, 52), (21, 53), (22, 47), (22, 48), (22, 49), (22, 50), (22, 51), (22, 52), (22, 53), (23, 47), (23, 48), (23, 49), (23, 50), (23, 51), (23, 52), (23, 53)]
```

Now I order it by it's distance to f1 and f2. With the example above:

```
[(20, 50), (19, 50), (20, 49), (21, 50), (20, 51), (21, 51), ..., (15, 45), (25, 55)]
```

A lambda function can do the job:

```
sorted(f, key=lambda x: abs(f1-x[0]) + abs(f2-x[1]))
```

Output:

```
[(20, 50), (19, 50), (20, 49), (20, 51), (21, 50), (18, 50), (19, 49), (19, 51), ...]
```

**Issue 1:** How to modify the lambda function in order to get the values (21,51) before (18, 50) (a distance of 1 on each frequency is better than a distance of 2 on one frequency)?

**Issue 2:** Sorting a list is quite time-consuming (here it's only a 49 elts list, but in reality, it can have thousands of tuples). Is there a way to directly generate the final list and thus to skip the sorting step?

EDIT: Clarification for issue 2
I want to directly generate the final list. The only solution I could think of is a bit heavy:
Instead of:

```
f = [(a, b) for a in range(f1-3, f1+4) for b in range(f2-3, f2+4)]
```

Use:

```
f = [(f1, f2)] + [(a, b) for a in range(f1, f1+2) for b in range(f2, f2+2)] + [(a, b) for a in range(f1, f1-2, -1) for b in range(f2, f2-2, -1)] + ... Distance of 2 + Distance of 3 + so on
```

Aside from the heavy line, I create duplicates which can be eliminated by `list(set(f))` but then I lose the time gained by not sorting...

Thanks.

Comment: According to which value you want to sort? the value at 0th or 1st position? Please clarify.

Comment: Why don't you consider numpy for larger ranges? Sorting/calculation of the array will be much faster in comparison to list comprehensions.

Comment: @MrT Because I'm not used to it, if you have a solution with numpy arrays I would be glad to see it.

Comment: If you don't want to use numpy, then there will be no advantage to have it as an intermediate step. You gain time from array operations in numpy (around a 1/10th of the comparable list comprehension solution), but this gain will be nearly eaten up by mapping the array back to a list of tuples.

Comment: @MrT I can adapt the rest of the code to use numpy. I'm already using some numpy and itertools functions in my code. But why is it faster? I mean it's just a different type of container with the same type of algorithm to do sorting behind no ?

Comment: For Vlad's idea, you have to square and add values for the comparison. Numpy vectorises these operations and is therefore faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue 1 I would go with the answer posted by @vlad : use a geometric distance.

Assuming this suits you, you can look at issue 2 in geometric terms : let f1 be the X axis and f2 the Y axis. Frequency tuples at an equal distance of (f1, f2) will be on a circle around (f1, f2). It doesn't matter where the center point (f1, f2) lies, the closest points will always be at the same (x, y) offset from (f1, f2). This means you can calculate once and for all the ordering of these offsets, then add them to whatever (f1, f2) you are interested in.

```
# do this once, and keep this variable around
offsets = [(a, b) for a in range(-3, +4) for b in range(-3, +4)]
offsets.sort(key=lambda x: x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2) 

# for any f1, f2 get the closest tuples
closest = [(f1 + o[0], f2 + o[1]) for o in offsets]
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll probably use this for my current algorithm version where the range is constant. But in a future version, the range (i.e. the cercle radius, will be in % of f1 and f2). For instance `a in range(-10% of f1, +10% of f1)` and `b in range(-5% of f2, +5% of f2)`. We agree that your solution can't be adapted for this scenario since it's no longer possible to compute the radius (offsets) beforehand? (Or you got an other idea ? ^^)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Issue 1 you could use geometric distance measure:

```
import math
...
sorted(f, key=lambda x: math.sqrt(pow(f1-x[0],2) + pow(f2-x[1],2)))
```

Comment: @Mathieu my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use standard deviation of distances as a second key. This has the benefit of combining your 2 pieces of sorting logic in one algorithm.

```
import numpy as np

f1 = 20
f2 = 50
f = [(a, b) for a in range(f1-3, f1+4) for b in range(f2-3, f2+4)]

res = sorted(f, key=lambda x: [abs(f1-x[0]) + abs(f2-x[1]),
                               np.std([abs(f1-x[0]), abs(f2-x[1])])])

# [(20, 50), (19, 50), (20, 49), (20, 51), (21, 50), (19, 49), (19, 51), (21, 49), (21, 51), (18, 50), (20, 48), (20, 52), (22, 50), (18, 49), (18, 51), (19, 48), (19, 52), (21, 48), (21, 52), (22, 49), (22, 51), (17, 50), (20, 47), (20, 53), (23, 50), (18, 48), (18, 52), (22, 48), (22, 52), (17, 49), (17, 51), (19, 47), (19, 53), (21, 47), (21, 53), (23, 49), (23, 51), (17, 48), (17, 52), (18, 47), (18, 53), (22, 47), (22, 53), (23, 48), (23, 52), (17, 47), (17, 53), (23, 47), (23, 53)]
```

Comment: (20, 48) got a distance of 2 and is sorted before (21, 49) or (19, 49).